# Use WebSVN as default HTML view

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

when opening an subversion URL like https://server.local/svn/reproname using a normal webbrowser I get a (not very nice but useful) webpage showing me the files of the highest revision of the repository.

Is it possible to change this HTML-view to use WebSVN instead? So I want to use the same URL for TortoiseSVN which then browses the repository using WebDAV and for browsing it with a webbrowser getting the nice interface of WebSVN.

I am using Apache 2.2 on an Win 2003 Server with mod_dav_svn.

Thanks in advance for any help.

sc911

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using mod_rewrite? You could do something like this:-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}          !^SVN.*
RewriteRule ^/svn/(.*?)(/.*)$           http://websvn.host/websvn/listing.php?repname=$1&path=$2      [R]
```

This should redirect any client that doesn't have a User-Agent string starting with 'SVN/' to a WebSVN installation at http://websvn.host/websvn/, and leave queries from SVN clients alone.

Comment: Interesting but it could break some third party svn clients

Comment: Great idea! Didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Hi Alexandre,

Yeah - I'm aware it could cause issues with some, but it's a start :-). If it's that much of a problem, you could flip the User-Agent stuff and only redirect to WebSVN if it positively matches for Mozilla or such.

Answer (score 1):

I too tried to get it to work like this, but I don't think it's possible. According to [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html) site, mod_dav_svn generates the html page you see, and it only supports simple skinning using xslt.

What I did was use a new virtual host for my WebSVN content (eg https://websvn.server.local/svn/reponame).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with mod_rewrite as Andy suggested. I am using this set of rules now

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SVN.*
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=3] 
RewriteRule ^svn$ /svn/ [R,N]
RewriteRule ^svn/$ /websvn/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^svn/(.*?)(/.*)$ /websvn/listing.php?repname=$1&path=$2 [R,L]
```

This checks for the User-Agent to start with SVN (this is how Tortoise identifies) and then skips the next three rules.

Those three rules are doing the following:

- add the trailing slash to the svn-URL (not done automatically because svn is no directory)
- redirect the direct access to the repository list
- redirect direct repository view

All this is done in the `<Directory>`-directive of the RootDir.

Thanks Andy for this hint!

sc911

Comment: No worries - glad it was useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working but it took much more than others have suggested.

I found that:

- TortoiseSVN and SVN only react to 301: "moved permanently".
- TortoiseSVN lies about it's user agent as "Mozilla compatible"
- TortoiseSVN places cookies that effect future accesses (hampering testing)

  ```
  RewriteEngine On

  #If it is not tortoise/SVN skip the next rule
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^SVN.*
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Mozilla/4.*compatible.*
  RewriteRule (.*) - [S=1]

  #Here it is tortoise/SVN we map / to /svn
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/svn.*
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /svn/$1 [R=301,L]

  #If it is not tortoise/SVN then it's a real browser, point to index
  #then redirect / to /opt/websvn
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^SVN.*
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Mozilla/4.*compatible.*
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/websvn.*

  RewriteRule ^/$ /opt/websvn/index.php

  #Redirect websvn/repos/path to listing.php
  RewriteRule ^websvn/(.*?)(/.*)$ /websvn/listing.php?repname=$1&path=$2 [R,L]

  Alias /websvn /opt/websvn
  <Directory /opt/websvn>
          Options +ExecCGI
          AddHandler cgi-script .php
          DirectoryIndex index.php
  </Directory>

  <Location /svn>
          DAV svn
          SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn
          SVNListParentPath On
  </Location>
  ```